# Using id_rsa and id_rsa.pub from ubuntu to windows?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, mercurial, ssh

Is it possible to use my id_rsa and id_rsa.pub from ubuntu to windows?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, [assuming you use Putty](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/putty-rsa-dsa-keys/)